# split csv files, but ignore new lines between quotes in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a CSV reader, however, I have an issue that some of the CSV fields can have multi-line data in them, so when you split them by new line, it actually splits those fields as well.

Basically what I'm trying to do is ignore any /n's that are between quotes, so that it splits the lines correctly.

Here is my attempt so far, but this doesn't seem to work

```
private static string[] SplitCsvLines(string input)
    {
        //Excludes new lines within quotes  
        var csvSplit = new Regex("(?:^|/n)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var list = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in csvSplit.Matches(input))
        {
            var curr = match.Value;
            if (0 == curr.Length)
            {
                list.Add("");
            }

            list.Add(curr.TrimStart(','));
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Could you show an example of some input and the expected output? Have you tried using a library to handle CSV reading/writing so you don't have to code it yourself?

Comment: You might remove these newlines before processing the csv.

Comment: If you add the RegexOptions.Singleline, then . will match newline, but you'll have to restructure your regex to use it.  Something like ((\"(.*)?\"(?!\"))|((?!\")[^,]*?)(,|$).  String will be in $3 if quoted or $4 if not quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is insufficient for this purpose. CSV data, which has to be analyzed by Regex, is simply too complex. You have to deal with topics such as escaping, line breaks, error handling of incorrect data, maintainability of the code and so on. Since regex complicates this management, it is not a suitable tool. I therefore recommend the use of a library (**CsvHelper** is a very good and high-performance library that receives regular updates).